# Is it possible to digitally sign an Adobe LiveCycle HTML Form?

Tags: html, forms, adobe, digital-signature, livecycle

Is possible to digitally sign an Adobe LiveCycle HTML Form ?

I know that with IBM Lotus Forms you can sign forms, rendered as HTML with an ActiveX control.

Answer (score 3):

No, the Adobe LiveCycle Digital Signatures is design to use in PDF only.

Reference:

- http://www.adobe.com/products/livecycle/digitalsignatures/

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure, I will have to try it myself. But here are a few pointers that may answer your question.

[LiveCycle documentation])http://help.adobe.com/en_US/enterpriseplatform/10.0/programLC/help/index.htm?content=000610.html)! says the following:
" Digitally signing HTML forms
You cannot sign an HTML form that contains a digital signature field if the form is rendered as one of the following HTML transformations:
AHTML HTML4 StaticHTML NoScriptXHTML "

XDP Form can be rendered in other formats as well, MSDHTML being one of them. Hence that need to be tried out.

Hope this helps. Goodluck.